# SQLalchemy ORM add to session with dynamic column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have 2 tables (not the true setup of my database).

### tableclass.py:

```
class TableMeaningEN(sqla_base):
    __tablename__ = 'MeaningEN'

    id = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer, primary_key=True)
    meaning = sqla.Column(sqla.String, primary_key=True)

class TableReadingON(sqla_base):
    __tablename__ = 'ReadingON'

    id = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer, primary_key=True)
    reading = sqla.Column(sqla.String, primary_key=True)
```

### Different column names

As you can see, both have a column `id`, but `TableMeaningEN` has `meaning` and `TableReadingON` has `reading`.

Normally (assuming you already have a session) you would add something like this:

```
session.add(TableMeaningEN(id=1, meaning='test'))
```

However I want to add dynamically entries to tables, so I have:

```
import tableclass as tc
for t_name in ['MeaningEN', 'ReadingON']:
    session.add(getattr(tc, 'Table{}'.format(t_name))(id=1, ??='test'))
```

### Question

How do I solve the problem that `??` is in one table `meaning` and in the other `reading`?

### Tried:

```
columns = sqla.inspect(getattr(tc, 'Table{}'.format(overwrite))).columns.keys()
session.add(getattr(tc, 'Table{}'.format(t_name))(id=1, columns[1]='test'))
```

I tried this, but however that's not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If tables are really different by just one attribute, you could create a constructor for both which takes positional arguments as well, such as:

```
class TableMeaningEN(sqla_base):
    def __init__(self, id, meaning):
        self.id, self.meaning = id, meaning

# similar __init__ for the other class/table

# then use the following:
session.add(getattr(tc, 'Table{}'.format(t_name))(1, 'test'))
```

An alternative would be to dynamically create the keyword arguments, assuming there is naming convention:

```
import tableclass as tc

for t_name in ['MeaningEN', 'ReadingON']:
    cls = getattr(tc, 'Table{}'.format(t_name))
    fld_name = t_name.lower()[:-2]
    kw = {'id': 1, fld_name: 'test'}
    session.add(cls(**kw))
```